# How reliable is onAnimationEndListener?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I made an mediaplayer app with animations when the users plays the next song, the album art fades out and the album art for the next song fades in.

I first start the fade out animation and if this animation ends i send a broadcast to start the second song.

I would like to know if `onAnimationEnd` is reliable and will always called because if not then my app basically wouldn't work anymore for playing next/prev song.

```
private void nextSong(){

        mAlbumArtLarge.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
        mAlbumIvBottom.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
        mAlbumArt.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
        tvSongTitle.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
        tvArtistName.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
        tvSongListSize.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);

        fadeOutAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if (Main.getInstance().mServiceIsBound) {
                    Main.getInstance().mediaPlayerService.startActionNextSong(getApplication(), songList, songIndex);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: In what situations do you think the method wouldn't be called? From the docs: "*This callback is not invoked for animations with repeat count set to INFINITE.*" - So if the animation is set to infinite, it won't be called. Other than that, I don't see any reason why the callback would be unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it wasn't called in case you run an animation during the start `onCreate()`of activity in `view.post{ startAnimation() }` and by going to background during beginning of animation it didn't called the listener. Eventually the problem for me was usage of `post(Runnable)` on queue to execute on main thread, as it was called in `onCreate()`. I had resolved it by using `onWindowFocusChanged()` + `post{}`. Will update my answer after sometime of using it in production. For now tested it on different devices/APIs no problem occurred.

To think of : you can add some (safety workaround) Handler with timer (like 5 sec if animation doesn't ends you do next step there after 5s)